# ArrayList to Object[][]

Tags: java, arrays, object, arraylist

I need to convert an Array List to Object[][], I have tried several different methods, and all seem to toss up an error or two.

My latest try is this:

```
Object[][] array = dataList.toArray(new Object[dataList.size()][]);
```

This throws the following error:

```
java.lang.ArrayStoreException
    at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
    at java.util.ArrayList.toArray(Unknown Source)
```

My array list is populated with classes I made, this is the class:

```
class dataClass {
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
    String string1;
    String string2;
    Date date;
    int event;

    public dataClass(int x, int y, int z, String string1, String string2,
            Date date, int event) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
        this.string1 = string1;
        this.string2 = string2;
        this.date = date;
        this.event = event;
    }
}
```

This is how I initialize my array list:

```
public static List<dataClass> dataList = new ArrayList<dataClass>();
```

I then add my new dataClass via:

```
.add(new dataClass(...));
```

Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: How do you expect the elements in the `ArrayList` to be stored in the `Object[][]`?

Comment: I see an additional dimension popping out of nowhere with no apparent reason, can you elaborate?

Comment: The people of flatland demand an answer

Comment: It is convention to start a class name, in Java, with an uppercase letter. Please review the Java Tutorials: [Variables and Naming](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html).

Comment: Can you show us your 'toArray' method?

Comment: @ScubaSteve I assume `dataList` is a `java.util.ArrayList`.

Comment: @ScubaSteve : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray()

Comment: Oh that's right, there it is.

Comment: As to why I am trying to convert it, I am trying to use Apache Commons DbUtils Batch. `public int[] batch(String sql,
          Object[][] params)` is what I am trying to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not completely specified, but here's my best guess for what you want:

```
Object[][] array = new Object[dataList.size()][];
int i = 0;
for (DataClass c : dataList)
{
    array[i] = new Object[7];
    array[i][0] = c.x;
    array[i][1] = c.y;
    array[i][2] = c.z;
    array[i][3] = c.string1;
    array[i][4] = c.string2;
    array[i][5] = c.date;
    array[i][6] = c.event;
    i++;
}
```

As to whether this is good design or not, without an explanation of what you're trying to accomplish, I can't really comment.  This does what I think you want, but the underlying design would give me pause.  I would try to understand the objective and then write it in a more Java-idiomatic manner.

Answer (score 1):

You have arraylist containing dataClass objects. You can convert that into one dimensional array and not two dimensional array.

dataClass [] dataArr = dataList.toArray(new dataClass [dataList.size()]);